# How often is "/me/drive/recent" refreshed?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using a Microsoft Graph query: "/v1.0/me/drive/recent".  It returns a set of documents as expected BUT:

More than 24 hours ago, I did the following:

1. I deleted a SharePoint site.  The recent query is still returning results from the deleted SharePoint site.
2. I added documents to a MS Teams SharePoint site.  Those documents are not being returned.

How often is "/v1.0/me/drive/recent" query updated?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the "/v1.0/me/drive/recent" query updating after you added the file. But the response contains just a file that was created in UI by this option. I don't see files that I uploaded from my PC in response.

[image]